# Multiple calculations in html / javascript code - text box data entry

Tags: javascript, html

I have asked this question before but have had to clean it up, difficult to follow, cause it was a mess, so its down to the bone now, in the format below the code works, the issue I am having is that I want to add a second and third equation using the same variables, possibly a forth, I thought I could just add another equation in the same format below and would work (different ID), but its not, it calculates one and not the other, its for a stand alone computer, no internet, can't use any plugins either, been at it a while now and its annoying me but I am determined to get it to work. Its google chrome being used. Is this possible, any one help please. I have set the code back to calculating just the one equation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                CMCObj = document.getElementById('txtCMC');
                WaterObj = document.getElementById('txtWater');
                GlycerolObj = document.getElementById('txtGlycerol');
                FlowObj = document.getElementById('txtFlow');
                FreshObj = document.getElementById('tdFresh');
                document.getElementById('btnReset').onclick = resetInputs;
                document.getElementById('btnCalc').onclick = calcAddition;
            };
            function resetInputs() {
                CMCObj.value = '';
                WaterObj.value = '';
                GlycerolObj.value = '';
                FlowObj.value = '';
                FreshObj.innerHTML = '';
            }
            function calcAddition() {
                var CMC = new Number(CMCObj.value);
                var Water = new Number(WaterObj.value);
                var Glycerol = new Number(GlycerolObj.value);
                var Flow = new Number(FlowObj.value);
                FreshObj.innerHTML = '';
                if (isNaN(CMC) || isNaN(Water)) {
                    alert('Invalid CMC or Water');
                    return;
                }
                FreshObj.innerHTML = Math.round(
                    ((CMC + Water + Glycerol) / (CMC + Water + Glycerol + Flow)) * 100
                );
            }
        </script>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="txtCMC">Total CMC Injection (ml)</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtCMC" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="txtWater">Total Water Injection (ml)</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtWater" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="txtGlycerol">Total Glycerol Injection (%)</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtGlycerol" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="txtFlow">Plasticiser Flow (Lhr)</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtFlow" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total Fresh Injection (%)</td>
                <td id="tdFresh"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <button id="btnReset">Reset</button
                    ><button id="btnCalc">Calculate</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Fixed code below and it works, thanks for help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>


<BODY>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload=function() {
                CMCObj = document.getElementById('txtCMC');
        WaterObj = document.getElementById('txtWater');
                GlycerolObj = document.getElementById('txtGlycerol');
        FlowObj = document.getElementById('txtFlow');
                FreshObj = document.getElementById('tdFresh');
        FreshCMCObj = document.getElementById('tdFreshCMC');
        FreshGlycerolObj = document.getElementById('tdFreshGlycerol');
        document.getElementById('btnReset').onclick = resetInputs;
                document.getElementById('btnCalc').onclick = calcAddition;
            }
            function resetInputs() {
                CMCObj.value = '';
        WaterObj.value = '';
                GlycerolObj.value = '';
                FlowObj.value = '';
                FreshObj.innerHTML = '';
        FreshCMCObj.innerHTML = '';
        FreshGlycerolObj.innerHTML = '';
        }
            function calcAddition() {
                var CMC = new Number(CMCObj.value);
        var Water = new Number(WaterObj.value);
                var Glycerol = new Number(GlycerolObj.value);
        var Flow = new Number(FlowObj.value);
                FreshObj.innerHTML = '';
                if(isNaN(CMC) || isNaN(Water)) {
                    alert('Invalid CMC or Water');
                    return;
        }
        FreshCMCObj.innerHTML = '';
                if(isNaN(CMC) || isNaN(Water)) {
                    alert('Invalid CMC or Water');
                    return;
        }
        FreshGlycerolObj.innerHTML = '';
                if(isNaN(CMC) || isNaN(Water)) {
                    alert('Invalid CMC or Water');
                    return;
        }
                FreshObj.innerHTML = Math.round(((CMC+Water+Glycerol)/(CMC+Water+Glycerol+Flow)*100));
        FreshCMCObj.innerHTML = Math.round(((CMC)/(CMC+Water+Glycerol+Flow)*100));
        FreshGlycerolObj.innerHTML = Math.round(((CMC+Water+Glycerol)/(CMC+Water+Glycerol+Flow)*100));
                }

        </script>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="txtCMC">Total CMC Injection (ml)</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtCMC" /></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><label for="txtWater">Total Water Injection (ml)</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtWater" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="txtGlycerol">Total Glycerol Injection (%)</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtGlycerol" /></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><label for="txtFlow">Plasticiser Flow (Lhr)</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtFlow" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total Fresh Injection (%)</td>
                <td id="tdFresh"></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>Total Fresh CMC Injection (%)</td>
                <td id="tdFreshCMC"></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>Total Fresh Glycerol Injection (%)</td>
                <td id="tdFreshGlycerol"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><button id="btnReset">Reset</button><button id="btnCalc">Calculate</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please give an example of the 2nd/3rd/4th equations you wish to implement. I know you've attempted to describe it, but it's not clear exactly why / what is happening to cause issues, because as far as I can see, your code here if functional.

Comment: Hi, the other equations are just a variation of the first,             
2nd equation FreshCMCObj.innerHTML = Math.round(((CMC)/(CMC+Water+Glycerol+Flow)*100));                   3rd equation FreshGlycerolObj.innerHTML = Math.round(((Glycerol)/(CMC+Water+Glycerol+Flow)*100));

Comment: And.. how does the program know which equation to use?

Comment: Hi, the other equations are just a variation of the first,             
2nd equation FreshCMCObj.innerHTML = Math.round(((CMC)/(CMC+Water+Glycerol+Flow)*100));                   3rd equation FreshGlycerolObj.innerHTML = Math.round(((Glycerol)/(CMC+Water+Glycerol+Flow)*100)); I just presumed that the FreshObj.innerHTML could be varied and placed below as such FreshCMCObj.innerHTML provided I done the getElementbyID code

Comment: Hi, your code currently has no reference to an object title `FreshCMCObj`, could you please update your code to reference this object, as well as implement the other 3 equations. From there I can try to implement something & fully understand what you mean, as it is not clear from the unformatted comments what is meant to happen. Thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help, its really appreciated, I must have had a wrong name or something in the code and never noticed before, Got it working after all this time, that's what happens when you cut and paste your own code, got that many variations of the code, I have added the new code above to let you see, if interested. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I made a few changes to your code making your calculator fully dynamic.  If you change the FormMaker function's TotalForms variable to any number... thats how many calculators it will make for you.  enjoy

:)

Also, I almost forgot to mention.  Your JS script needs to be placed at the end of your HTML document and never on top. There are ways to place your JS at the top, but it should be done with built workarounds to avoid errors in your code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>My Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="FormArea"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

//setTimeout(FormMaker, 0);
                (function StartingApp(){
                        setTimeout(FormMaker, 6);   
                })();                 
         function FormMaker() {
            let TotalForms = 3,
                    i,
                fragment,
                div,
                htmlText,
                Location = document.querySelector('#FormArea');
                console.log(Location);

            for (i = 0; i < TotalForms; i++) {
                    console.log('hello');
                fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
                div = document.createElement('div');
                htmlText = `
                <h2>Amazing Calculator ${i+1}</h2>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="txtCMC">Total CMC Injection (ml)</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtCMC${i}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td><label for="txtWater">Total Water Injection (ml)</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtWater${i}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="txtGlycerol">Total Glycerol Injection (%)</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtGlycerol${i}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td><label for="txtFlow">Plasticiser Flow (Lhr)</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtFlow${i}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Total Fresh Injection (%)</td>
                        <td id="tdFresh${i}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <button id="btnReset${i}" onclick = "resetInputs()">Reset</button>
                            <button id="btnCalc${i}" onclick = "calcAddition()">Calculate</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                `;
                div.className = 'FormContainers';
                div.innerHTML = htmlText;
                fragment.appendChild(div);
                Location.appendChild(fragment);
            };
        };
        function resetInputs() {
            let i,
                TotalForms = document.getElementsByClassName("FormContainers").length;

          for (i = 0; i < TotalForms; i++) {
              let CMCObj = document.getElementById(`txtCMC${i}`),
                    WaterObj = document.getElementById(`txtWater${i}`),
                    GlycerolObj = document.getElementById(`txtGlycerol${i}`),
                    FlowObj = document.getElementById(`txtFlow${i}`),
                    FreshObj = document.getElementById(`tdFresh${i}`);
                            CMCObj.value = '';
              WaterObj.value = '';
              GlycerolObj.value = '';
              FlowObj.value = '';
              FreshObj.innerHTML = '';
            };
        };

        function calcAddition() {
          let i,
          TotalForms = document.getElementsByClassName("FormContainers").length;  

          for (i = 0; i < TotalForms; i++) {
                            let CMC = document.getElementById(`txtCMC${i}`).value,
                    Water = document.getElementById(`txtWater${i}`).value,
                    Glycerol = document.getElementById(`txtGlycerol${i}`).value,
                    Flow = document.getElementById(`txtFlow${i}`).value,
                    FreshObj = document.getElementById(`tdFresh${i}`);
                            FreshObj.innerHTML = '';
                    if(isNaN(CMC) || isNaN(Water)) {
                        alert(`Invalid CMC or Water on Amazing Calculator ${i}`);
                    return;
                  }
                  FreshObj.innerHTML = Math.round(((CMC+Water+Glycerol)/(CMC+Water+Glycerol+Flow)*100));
          };
        };

</script>
<style>
#FormArea{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

</style>

</body>
</html>
```